# Need to mark paid installments in an array using mongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a schema named orders which looks like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd42f7b16c2654ea9138ece"),
    "customerId" : ObjectId("5c8222109146d119ccc5243f"),
    "orderAmount" : NumberInt(10000),
    "paidAmount" : NumberInt(4000),
    "installments" : [
        {
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-01-01"),
            "amount" : NumberInt(2000)
        },
        {
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-01-07"),
            "amount" : NumberInt(6000)
        },
        {
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-01-04"),
            "amount" : NumberInt(2000)
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to write an aggregation function that sorts the installments according to dueDate and mark them paid according to paidAmount. For example for this case the function should return

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd42f7b16c2654ea9138ece"),
    "customerId" : ObjectId("5c8222109146d119ccc5243f"),
    "orderAmount" : NumberInt(10000),
    "paidAmount" : NumberInt(4000),
    "installments" : [
        {
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-01-01"),
            "amount" : NumberInt(2000),
            "paid" : true
        },
        {
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-01-04"),
            "amount" : NumberInt(2000),
            "paid" : true
        },
        {
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-01-07"),
            "amount" : NumberInt(6000),
            "paid" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I can sort the array using the $unwind and $sort functions like this:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$installments"},
    {$sort : {"dueDate" : 1}}
]);
```

What I am stuck on is how to group the array back so that it gives me the desired result. I can only use aggregation here.

Comment: So you want add `paid` field if `amount < paidAmount` ? Also sort `installments` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `$group` installments. But, if you need to put `paid` field with some logic, it's necessary to add extra pipeline stages.

**ASSUMPTION**

`paidAmount` value calculated by ordered `installments.[].paid`

```
paidAmount    installments.[].paid
4000       <= 2000(t) 2000(t) 6000(f)
4000       <≠ 2000(t) 6000(f) 2000(f)
4000       <≠ 6000(f) 2000(f) 2000(f)
6000       <= 6000(t) 2000(f) 2000(f)
6000       <≠ 1000(t) 6000(f) 1000(f)
6000       <= 1000(t) 4000(t) 1000(t)
```

**EXPLANATION `paid:true|false` LOGIC**

We order installments and create extra `tmp`  field with installments value (for `paid` field).

For each `installments` item <sub>i</sub>, we mark `paid:true` if `paidAmount` - `sum(amount`<sub>0 - i</sub>`) >= 0`.

---

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$installments"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "installments.dueDate": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      orders: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      },
      installments: {
        $push: "$installments"
      },
      tmp: {
        $push: "$installments"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$installments"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "installments.paid": {
        $cond: [
          {
            $gte: [
              {
                $reduce: {
                  input: {
                    $slice: [
                      "$tmp",
                      {
                        $sum: [
                          {
                            $indexOfArray: [
                              "$tmp",
                              "$installments"
                            ]
                          },
                          1
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  initialValue: "$orders.paidAmount",
                  in: {
                    $sum: [
                      {
                        $multiply: [
                          "$$this.amount",
                          -1
                        ]
                      },
                      "$$value"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          true,
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      customerId: {
        $first: "$orders.customerId"
      },
      orderAmount: {
        $first: "$orders.orderAmount"
      },
      paidAmount: {
        $first: "$orders.paidAmount"
      },
      installments: {
        $push: "$installments"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wG3aPgy5U2Q)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{ $unwind: '$installments' },{ $sort: { 'installments.dueDate': 1 } },
{ $addFields: { 'installments.paid': { $cond: [{ $lte: ["$installments.amount", '$paidAmount'] }, true, false] } } },
{ $group: { _id: '$id', data: { $first: '$$ROOT' }, installments: { $push: '$installments' } } },
{ $addFields: { 'data.installments': '$installments' } },
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd42f7b16c2654ea9138ece"),
    "customerId" : ObjectId("5c8222109146d119ccc5243f"),
    "orderAmount" : 10000,
    "paidAmount" : 4000,
    "installments" : [ 
        {
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-01-01T21:21:20.202Z"),
            "amount" : 2000
        }, 
        {
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-01-07T21:27:20.202Z"),
            "amount" : 6000
        }, 
        {
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-01-04T21:24:20.202Z"),
            "amount" : 2000
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd42f7b16c2654ea9138ece"),
    "customerId" : ObjectId("5c8222109146d119ccc5243f"),
    "orderAmount" : 10000,
    "paidAmount" : 4000,
    "installments" : [ 
        {
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-01-01T21:21:20.202Z"),
            "amount" : 2000,
            "paid" : true
        }, 
        {
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-01-04T21:24:20.202Z"),
            "amount" : 2000,
            "paid" : true
        }, 
        {
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-01-07T21:27:20.202Z"),
            "amount" : 6000,
            "paid" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)